# I have tried debugging the code but still i am not able to find the error. Function "getDonators" not found in contract

Tags: solidity, contract-debugging, react

````
import React, { useContext, createContext } from "react";
import {
  useAddress,
  useContract,
  useMetamask,
  useContractWrite,
} from "@thirdweb-dev/react";
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import { parse } from "dotenv";

const StateContext = createContext();
export const StateContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const { contract } = useContract(
    "0x4ad98B13b90F7DFbBA0fF3b89b213c0dCaD31545"
    );
  const { mutateAsync: createCampaign, isLoading } = useContractWrite(
    contract,
    "createCampaign"
  );

  const address = useAddress();
  const connect = useMetamask();

  const publishCampaign = async (form) => {
    try {
      const data = await createCampaign({ args: [
        address,
        form.title,
        form.description,
        form.target,
        new Date(form.deadline).getTime(),
        form.image,
      ]});
      console.log("Contract call success", data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Contract call failure", error);
    }
  };

  const getCampaigns = async () => {
    const campaigns = await contract.call('getCampaigns');
    
    const parsedCampaigns = campaigns.map((campaign, i) => ({
      owner: campaign.owner,
      title: campaign.title,
      description: campaign.description,
      target: ethers.utils.formatEther(campaign.target.toString()),
      deadline: campaign.deadline.toNumber(),
      amountCollected: ethers.utils.formatEther(campaign.amountCollected.toString()),
      image: campaign.image,
      pId: i
    }));
    // console.log(parsedCampaigns);
    return parsedCampaigns;
  }

  const getUserCampaigns = async () => {
    const allCampaigns = await getCampaigns();

    const filteredCampaigns = allCampaigns.filter((campaign) => 
    campaign.owner === address);

    return filteredCampaigns;
  }

  const donate = async (pId, amount) => {
    const data = await contract.call('donateToCampaign', pId, {
    value: ethers.utils.parseEther(amount)
    });

    return data;
  }

  const getDonations = async (pId) => {
    const donations = await contract.call('getDonators', pId);
    const numberofDonations = donations[0].length;

    const parsedDonations = [];

    for(let i=0; i<numberofDonations; i++){
      parsedDonations.push({
        donator: donations[0][i],
        donation: ethers.utils.formatEther(donations[1][i].toString())
      })
    }
    return parsedDonations;
  }

  return (
    <StateContext.Provider
      value={{
        address,
        contract,
        connect,
        createCampaign: publishCampaign,
        getCampaigns,
        getUserCampaigns, 
        donate,
        getDonations,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </StateContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useStateContext = () => useContext(StateContext);


``` require("@matterlabs/hardhat-zksync-solc");

/** @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig */
module.exports = {
  zksolc: {
    version: "1.3.9",
    compilerSource: "binary",
    settings: {
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
      },
    },
  },
  networks: {
    zksync_testnet: {
      url: "https://zksync2-testnet.zksync.dev",
      ethNetwork: "goerli",
      chainId: 280,
      zksync: true,
    },
    zksync_mainnet: {
      url: "https://zksync2-mainnet.zksync.io/",
      ethNetwork: "mainnet",
      chainId: 324,
      zksync: true,
    },
  },
  paths: {
    artifacts: "./artifacts-zk",
    cache: "./cache-zk",
    sources: "./contracts",
    tests: "./test",
  },
  solidity: {
    version: "0.8.17",
    defaultNetwork: 'goerli',
    networks: {
      hardhat: {},
      goerli: {
        url: 'https://rpc.ankr.com/eth_goerli',
        accounts: ['0x${process.env.PRIVATE_KEY}']
      }
    },
    settings: {
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 200,
      },
    },
  },
};
````

Comment: Can you include the ABI used and full error? I see the contract address in the code but on which network is it?

Comment: It's on goerli test network and I have added hardhat config.js file